# Extracting horizontal lines and text from PDF in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

The PDF is https://www.pdf-archive.com/2017/03/22/pdf/

I am looking to get a JSON file containing: reference, date, applicant, location and proposal. My first goal is to work out how to 'split' the pdf by horizontal line to extract each individual application.

I am using PyPDF2

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf','rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)         
print (pageObj.extractText())
```

however I cannot get this split to work. I've been trying to get PyPDF2 to print out everything it 'sees' from the PDF but can't do that either.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

`PyPDF2` was deprecated in favor of `pypdf`. I'm the maintainer of both projects.

The text extraction of `pypdf` got massively improved in 2022. Please try again with the latest version of pypdf:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

See https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

Please also note that pypdf cannot read text from images. pypdf is not OCR software, but only handling PDF. If you need OCR, try tesseract. See https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html#ocr-vs-text-extraction